# TIのセンサータグ CC2650をIoT Foundationに接続するためにはどうしたら良いか？

Tags: bluemix

ハッカソンにて、以下のTI社のCC2650STKのセンサーをIoT Foundationに接続し情報を取得したいと考えております。
http://www.tij.co.jp/tool/jp/cc2650stk

このときインターネット経由でIoT Foundationに接続し、Bluemixから情報を取得する場合、どのように接続したらよろしいでしょうか？特別なデバイスが必要となりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ご質問のSensor Tag CC2650のセンサーデータをインターネット経由でCloud環境に送信する方法ですが、スマートフォンをゲートウェイとして使用する方法と、BeagleBone Blackといった安価小型コンピュータ（他にRaspberry Pi等）にLinux等のOSを載せゲートウェイとして使用する方法の二つがあります。

**スマートフォンを使用する場合**は、接続用のiOS用のアプリが用意されており、アプリを使うことでIoT Foundationに簡単に接続することが可能であり、一番コストがかからない方法かと思います。ガイドは下記になります。

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connect-a-cc2650-sensortag-to-the-iot-foundations-quickstart/

**同じTI社のBeagleBone Blackを使用する場合**は、例えばLinuxを導入し、センサーとの通信やインターネット環境に接続するための設定等が必要となり、ガイドとしては下記が参考になります。BeagleBone Blackは7~8000円程度で入手可能なボードコンピュータで、別途センサーとBluetooth通信するためUSB ドングル（1000円～）も別途必要となります。

https://deskinhursley.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/bluemix-internet-of-things-workshop-with-texas-instruments-beaglebone-and-sensortag/
https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/ti-beaglebone-sensortag/

Comment: 回答でスマートフォンを使用する場合の、リンクが途切れており、参照出来ません。 同様のリンクなどございましたら、教えてください。 よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @kazuhiro サイト構造が変わっただけのようで、記事名らしき部分で検索したらそれらしいのが見つかりました。回答を修正したのでご確認ください。